# Spring boot application.properties with Oracle NoSql

Tags: spring, spring-boot, properties, oracle-nosql

I've been looking for information about create an spring boot application with connection to a Oracle NoSql Database, but i only have found info about mongoDB projects.... how can i set up my application.properties to catch the driver, url, database... etc of Oracle NoSql? I mean, for MongoDB i could find this:

```
spring.data.mongodb.authentication-database= # Authentication database name.
spring.data.mongodb.database=test # Database name.
spring.data.mongodb.field-naming-strategy= # Fully qualified name of the FieldNamingStrategy to use.
spring.data.mongodb.grid-fs-database= # GridFS database name.
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost # Mongo server host.
spring.data.mongodb.password= # Login password of the mongo server.
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017 # Mongo server port.
spring.data.mongodb.repositories.enabled=true # Enable Mongo repositories.
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test # Mongo database URI. When set, host and port are ignored.
spring.data.mongodb.username= # Login user of the mongo server.
```

so, i was looking for something like:

```
spring.data.oracle-nosql.url = localhost
spring.data.oracle-nosql.driver-name=oracle-nosql-driver-name
```

Someone knows some tutorial or something to catch the data or, at least, get informed?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

the Spring Boot's auto-config modules for databases use Spring Data's implementations, and Oracle NoSql is not yet present on that list.

You can find this list following the link https://spring.io/projects/spring-data.

So, for you to make it work, you may need to implement it yourself.

Comment: my god... i was looking about jax-rs and something like that, but if you are correct.... it will be a hard work...

Comment: Why would it be hard work? Isn't it just a matter of connecting to the database and performing operations? Oracle NoSql has a java client library, you can just use it

Answer (score 0):

Alvaro, the sprint boot driver for Oracle NoSQL DB is currently in works and is due for release later this year. Can you write to me at your use-case and requirements?

Comment: Hi! well, we just wanted to use Oracle NoSql to map a full database, plus use it with an ORM like Hibernate, for example (like MongoDB), create criterias to access the database, and finally, implement it in a Spring Boot application. The missing thing in all this proyect is the Application.properties configuration, spring asks us for a spring.datasource.url for the database, but doesn't recognize anything from Oracle NoSql (i know that in Oracle (normal) is spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost and the driver spring.datasource.driver-class-oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver)

Comment: Alvaro, can you write at the Oracle NoSQL Community forums